# Weird $ behavior: ${\string}

Tags: perl

While I was experimenting, I found out that

```
print ${\string}
```

would print `string` to the screen.
Is this normal? Does this have a name?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The bareword "string" is being understood as a string you simply didn't quote.  `use strict` would prohibit this, and `use warnings` would have complained about it.

You are then taking a reference to the string (effectively, `my $ref = \"string";`), and dereferencing it (effectively, `${$ref}`).

It is "normal" in the sense that life without `strict` is sometimes both slippery and sharp-edged.

Comment: Also try `sub string { return 'foo' }; print ${\string}` which provides a different resolution to the bareword

Answer (score 7):

It's a reference to string being dereferenced with `${}`

```
perl -MO=Deparse -e "print ${\string}"
print ${\'string';};
```